# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\root n\of{a_n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence of positive terms, show that  if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ exists, then so does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\root n\of{a_n}$ and the two limits are equal.

Comment: I suggest that you dont use too much math script in your question title. It makes things troublesome.